# AWS - Terraform: Create Network ACL without assigning it to VPC

Tags: amazon-web-services, security, acl, amazon-vpc

I want to create a network ACL in terraform, but I do not want to assign it to any VPC.

I want to assign it to VPCs in later time.

Is this possible in any way?

As far as I understand from [here](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/network_acl) the `aws_network_acl` resource requires a `vpc_id` argument, therefore the only way I could work this around up to this point is by creating a dummy vpc:

```
resource "aws_vpc" "dummy" {
  cidr_block = "10.11.12.13/1"
}

resource "aws_network_acl" "blacklist" {
  vpc_id = aws_vpc.dummy.id

  tags = {
    name = "blacklist"
    team = "security"
  }

   egress {
    protocol   = -1
    rule_no    = 100
    action     = "allow"
    cidr_block = "0.0.0.0/0"
    from_port  = 0
    to_port    = 0
  }
}
```

Comment: No https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/APIReference/API_CreateNetworkAcl.html *"Creates a network ACL in a VPC"*. Why do you want to create the NACL first and the VPC later?

Comment: I want this NACL to act as a blacklist in which I will dynamically assign add IPs to be blocked, through a lambda function. Eventually, I will attach this NACL to all of of my companies VPC, but for now I want to create it without associating it with any VPC.

Comment: That can't be done with a single NACL. Your Lambda function would need to create the NACL in each VPC.

Comment: Have you tried attaching a single NACL to multiple VPCs already?

Comment: No, you are right guys, thank you. My approach is incorrect. I should probably use AWS Network Firewall instead.